# Internal Storage for Android; creating files

Tags: android, file, storage, internal

Im trying to just create basic files internally for another app. So i wrote a basic app to work out the kinks then was going to add it to the other app. Here is the log from the cat

```
10-09 17:56:14.579: D/dalvikvm(11092): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
10-09 17:56:15.599: E/Trace(11092): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-09 17:56:16.549: D/gralloc_goldfish(11092): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-09 17:57:20.158: D/dalvikvm(11092): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-09 17:57:30.078: E/Trace(11662): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-09 17:57:30.759: D/gralloc_goldfish(11662): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

The file is created. But when im implemented the code to create a file off the onClick it did not. Or when i put the file creating in a class other than the main class, it did not create the file.

here is my basic code:
    `package com.newapp;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    newFile();

}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public String timeStamp(){
        Date myDate = new Date();
        return (DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDate) + " " +                         DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(myDate));
    }

    public void newFile (){
         String FILENAME = timeStamp();
         String string = "hello world!";

         FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
         try {
                fos.write(string.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
         try {
                    fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`
```

I got rid of the button and other classes for now. This is all the code other than the normal hello worlds screen they give you and an unmodified manifest.

**EDIT**
The code above works i and a file is created in /data/data/com.newapp/files
Just ran it again to make sure a file is created and got this from the cat.

10-09 17:57:29.482: D/dalvikvm(11662): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
10-09 17:57:30.078: E/Trace(11662): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-09 17:57:30.759: D/gralloc_goldfish(11662): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-09 18:53:35.238: D/dalvikvm(11662): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-09 18:53:53.389: E/Trace(14975): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-09 18:53:54.658: I/Choreographer(14975): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-09 18:53:54.668: D/gralloc_goldfish(14975): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

I am going to move it to its own class now and try it.

Here is the file creation in its own class:
    package com.newapp;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;    
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class NewFile extends Activity {

public String timeStamp(){
    Date myDate = new Date();
    return (DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDate) + " " +             DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(myDate));
}

public NewFile (){
     String FILENAME = timeStamp();
     String string = "hello world!";

     FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
 }
```

And here is the Main activity:

```
package com.newapp;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    NewFile firstone = new NewFile();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}   
}
```

Finally I tried it a few different ways with having the NewFile(); as a constructor as just a regular method and calling firstone.newFile();
Having a lot of trouble it will not even run on the virtual device or tablet right now.

Comment: It looks like you posted code that works, and a logcat without a crash. Maybe post the code from `the button and other classes`, and the logcat from that(if it's even crashing, hard to tell from your post if it's crashing or just not creating a file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem with the help of a friend.
You cannot "extend activity" in the new class.
You need to use context to reference the class. The final code for the NewFile class is:

```
package com.newapp;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.content.Context;

public class NewFile{

public String timeStamp(){
    Date myDate = new Date();
    return (DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDate) + " " + DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(myDate));
}

public void createFile(Context c) throws IOException{
     String FILENAME = timeStamp();
     String string = "hello world!";

     FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();


}
}
```

and in the main class you just needed to call:

```
NewFile firstfile = new NewFile();
firstfile.createFile(getBaseContext());
```

In the onCreate method.

Thanks